# How to compare an input string to A set of lists and project output as the most matching one? [python]

Tags: python, project

As a beginner I have a few doubts about this project I'm working on
The general idea of this project is to allow users to be able to detect a certain disease through symptoms
I want the program to match the input with the provided lists and pick out the best match and print output.

The problem here is that the list provided with symptoms of diseases shares few common symptoms with each other. So the program must evaluate the entire set of lists and print the best match

I tried something

```py
import re

input1 = input("Enter Your Symptoms: ".lower())
x = re.split("\s", input1)  #used to seprate the words in the string and create a list out of it

# Symptoms
cadsym = ['chest pain' , 'body pain' , 'falling sick' , 'feeling faint' , 'shortness of breath']
vhdsym = ['swollen ankles' , 'fanting' , 'shortness of breath']
hasym = ['racing heartbeat', 'slow heartbeat', 'chest pain' , 'anxiety', 'sweating']
mhasym = ['cold sweat', 'heartburn', 'sudden dizziness', 'discomfort in joints']
jsym = ['itching', 'abdominal pain', 'weight loss', 'yellow eyes' , 'yellow nails', 'vomiting']
cpsym = ['rashes on skin' , 'fever' , 'sore throat' , 'brown spots' , 'itching']
msym = ['fever', 'runny nose' , 'sneezing' , 'pink eye' , 'skin rash', 'diarrhoea']
dsym = ['Eye pain' , 'fever' , 'muscle pain' , 'nausea' , 'joint pain', 'rash on thigh']
masym = ['pain in muscle' , 'pain in abdomin' , 'Night sweat' , 'shivering', 'fast heart rate' , 'mental confusion']
tcsym = ['chest pain','Night sweats','shortness of breath','blood cough']
disym = ['increase thirst','frequent urination','hunger','blurred vision','slow healing']
pnsym = ['fever','chills','sharp pain in chest','clammy skin']
htsym = ['nose bleeds','dizziness','morning headaches','irregular heart rhythms','vision changes','buzzing in the ears']
emsym = ['lot of mucus','tight chest','whistle sound while breathing']
cysym = ['bluish colour in sikn',' lips','nail beds']
hysym = ['itchy','red and watery eyes','rod of mouth being itchy','runny or blocked nose']
ansym = ['unusual headache','memory loss','slurred speech','forgotten words','trouble in walking','trouble in moving arms','trouble in moving legs']
hcsym = ['anxiety','shortness of breath','headache','daytime sleep even after sleeping a lot at night','daytime sluggishness']
bcsym = ['sleeping difficulty','sore throat','chest pressure','shortness of breath','runny nose']
asym = ['wheezing','anxiety','early awakening','shortness of breath at night','cough','throat irritation']

if x in cadsym:
    print("You Might Have Coronary Artery Disease")
elif x in vhdsym:
    print("You Might Have Vulvar Heart Disease")
elif x in hasym:
    print("You Might Have Heart Arrhythmia ")
elif x in mhasym:
    print("You Might Have Minor Heart Attack")
elif x in jsym:
    print("You Might Have Jaundice")    
elif x in cpsym:
    print("You Might Have Chickenpox")
elif x in msym:
    print("You Might Have Measles")
elif x in dsym:
    print("You Might Have Dengue")
elif x in masym:
    print("You Might Have Malaria")
elif x in tcsym:
    print("You Might Have Tuberculosis")
elif x in disym:
    print("You Might Have Diabetes")
elif x in pnsym:
    print("You Might Have Pneumonia")
elif x in htsym:
    print("You Might Have Hypertension")
elif x in emsym:
    print("You Might Have Emphysema")
elif x in cysym:
    print("You Might Have Cyanosis")
elif x in hysym:
    print("You Might Have Hay Fever")
elif x in ansym:
    print("You Might Have Anoxia")
elif x in hcsym:
    print("You Might Have Hypercapnia")
elif x in bcsym:
    print("You Might Have Bronchitis")
elif x in asym:
    print("You Might Have Asthama")   
else:
    print("Not Registered")
```

Comment: try to run `for loop on x` maintaining a temp_variable for each list. if `x in the list` increase temp_variable by 1 and last to check which temp_variable has more value and `print` the disease

Answer (score 0):

As the response for each case is the same sentence with just the disease name changing, why not use a dict where the key is the disease name and the value is the list of symptoms.

A bigger challenge here might be that many of the symptoms include spaces, so any split of the full input string is going to prevent you from finding matches.  For example, if the user enters `shortness of breath`, then x is going to contain `['shortness', 'of', 'breath']`
There are two possible work arounds for this:

1. Ask the user to input one symptom at a time and put all of the symptoms into a list
2. Split of the symptom lists to all be single words only, but that's going to get a lot more false positives.

Here's my solution using sets, prompting the user for separate symptoms, and putting all of the disease data into a single constant dictionary.

```
# Use a set for user symptoms to prevent duplicates, and so we can compare
# against our database easily later.
user_symptoms = set()
print("Enter your symptoms one at a time. Leave the entry blank to stop.")
while True:
    # .lower() needs to be OUTSIDE the input() call,
    #  otherwise it changes the prompt, not the input
    x = input("Enter a symptom: ").lower()
    if len(x):
        user_symptoms.add(x)
    else:
        break

# Dict of diseases with symptoms as sets.
# We can use sets instead of lists as ordering is not important.
DIAGNOSES = {
    "coronary artery disease": {'chest pain', 'body pain', 'falling sick', 'feeling faint', 'shortness of breath'},
    "vulvar heart disease":  {'swollen ankles', 'fanting', 'shortness of breath'},
    "heart arrhythmia": {'racing heartbeat', 'slow heartbeat', 'chest pain', 'anxiety', 'sweating'},
    "minor heart attack": {'cold sweat' 'heartburn', 'sudden dizziness', 'discomfort in joints'},
    "jaundice": {'itching', 'abdominal pain', 'weight loss', 'yellow eyes', 'yellow nails', 'vomiting'},
    "chickenpox": {'rashes on skin', 'fever', 'sore throat', 'brown spots', 'itching'},
    "measles": {'fever', 'runny nose', 'sneezing', 'pink eye', 'skin rash', 'diarrhoea'},
    "dengue": {'Eye pain', 'fever', 'muscle pain', 'nausea', 'joint pain', 'rash on thigh'},
    "malaria": {'pain in muscle', 'pain in abdomin', 'Night sweat', 'shivering', 'fast heart rate', 'mental confusion'},
    "tuberculosis": {'chest pain', 'Night sweats', 'shortness of breath', 'blood cough'},
    "diabetes": {'increase thirst', 'frequent urination', 'hunger', 'blurred vision', 'slow healing'},
    "pneumonia": {'fever', 'chills', 'sharp pain in chest', 'clammy skin'},
    "hypertension": {'nose bleeds', 'dizziness', 'morning headaches', 'irregular heart rhythms', 'vision changes', 'buzzing in the ears'},
    "emphysema": {'lot of mucus', 'tight chest', 'whistle sound while breathing'},
    "cyanosis": {'bluish colour in sikn', ' lips', 'nail beds'},
    "hay fever": {'itchy', 'red and watery eyes', 'rod of mouth being itchy', 'runny or blocked nose'},
    "anoxia": {'unusual headache', 'memory loss', 'slurred speech', 'forgotten words', 'trouble in walking', 'trouble in moving arms', 'trouble in moving legs'},
    "hypercapnia": {'anxiety', 'shortness of breath', 'headache', 'daytime sleep even after sleeping a lot at night', 'daytime sluggishness'},
    "bronchitis": {'sleeping difficulty', 'sore throat', 'chest pressure', 'shortness of breath', 'runny nose'},
    "asthma": {'wheezing', 'anxiety', 'early awakening', 'shortness of breath at night', 'cough', 'throat irritation'},
}

# Find any possible matches using set.intersection(). Put matches in a list.
matches = []
for dx, dx_symptoms in DIAGNOSES.items():
    if user_symptoms.intersection(dx_symptoms):
        matches.append(dx)


# Now print all the possible matches.
for match in matches:
    print(f"You might have {match}.")
else:
    print("No matching symptoms registered.")
```

Example run:

```
Enter your symptoms one at a time. Leave the entry blank to stop.
Enter a symptom: chest PAIN
Enter a symptom: anxiety 
Enter a symptom: hunger
Enter a symptom: SORE throat
Enter a symptom: 
You might have coronary artery disease.
You might have heart arrhythmia.
You might have chickenpox.
You might have tuberculosis.
You might have diabetes.
You might have hypercapnia.
You might have bronchitis.
You might have asthma.
```